# Change label spacing on ListPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to add a label to each point of my `ListPlot[]` by using the example from the documentation as a basis:

```
ListPlot[Labeled[#, #] & /@ Table[Prime[n], {n, 10}], 
         PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image: ListPlot labels]

Now I want to increase the spacing of the labels. `Labeled[]` has the option `Spacings` for this, but unfortunately, I can't combine them with my plot:

```
ListPlot[Labeled[#, #, Spacings -> {1, 1}] & /@ 
         Table[Prime[n], {n, 10}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

because it results in the following error:

> Labeled::labpos: "Spacings->{1,1} is not a valid position for the placement of labels. "

Is there any way around this problem?

Tested with Mathematica 10.4.1.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3rd position of [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) is position and dosn't require `Spacings`.

```
shiftX = -2;
shiftY = -0.6;

ListPlot[Table[Labeled[Prime[n], Prime[n], {-shiftX, -shiftY}], {n, 10}], DataRange -> All]
```

[image]